# Jquery validation - validating email through ajax call

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

What response should we pass back on ajax request for validating email?

My code .js

```
$("#create_account").validate({
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        console.log(error);


   },
   rules: {
    "User[password]" : {
      minlength : 6
    },
    confirm_password: {
      minlength : 6,
      equalTo: "#User_password"
    },
    "User[email]": {
            remote: "/app_dev.php/ajaxValidateFieldUser"
    }
  },
  messages: {
        "User[password]": {
            minlength: "Minimum 6 charecters"
        },
        confirm_password: {
             minlength: "Minimum 6 charecters",
             equalTo:"Password should match"
        }
  }

   });

   $('#User_email').on('blur', function() {
        $('#create_account').validate().element(this); // this triggers the single element validation
    });
```

I tried to return response from `ajaxValidateFieldUser` is true /false. But it is not showing nay difference.

And also is there any way to track specfic error in

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            console.log(error);


       }
```

For example I want to only highlight box if required condition fails.But if email is not unique I want to track response and want to display message in particular div.

Comment: `"User[email]"` should be the name of the html element. Is that the name you have given?

Comment: ya..it is default in Symfony 2 framework.It is fine because User[password] is working fine and my ajax request is going properly.But little confusion about what to return back.Is it expecting json format response?

Comment: you have to return true or the error message if false. validation will do the rest for you. and yes the result should be in json.

Comment: Can you give response format?

Comment: okay..I sent json_encode("Email already exists") as respose it worked.

Comment: How to display only this message in div. I dont want "field is required" to get displayed.

Comment: you can set the message for remote fields in the jquery validation. like you have already set for `minlength`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43115/discussion-between-anto-j-subash-and-stefun)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have return the true or the error message if false from your service. and the result should be in json.

here is the fiddle which will help you http://jsfiddle.net/35cHS/30/

for success try this

```
$response = new Response(json_encode(true)));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

for error try this

```
$response = new Response(json_encode("Enter new email address")));
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
return $response;
```

here is the docs for remote validation http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method/

Comment: hey @anto .thank you .It worked. Now I want to display only this message in div. I dont want "field is required" (Normal required field message) to get displayed.How to handle this?